# Create view of "My Sharepoint groups"

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups

We have a huge, classic portal, with several SharePoint groups (not O365 groups) for each customer like:

- customerA-Visitors, Members
- customerB-Visitors, Members
- ...

The group owners have rights to manage the group, but they don't have manage permissions rights on the portal itself. One person can manage multiple customers.
I would like to give them an interface to add/remove members to groups, like "Groups I own". I found workarounds, how to edit the view of the user information list and add extra fields, so I could apply a filter, but unfortunately the "Owner" is not there. How can I create such an view?

Comment: Do you want the users from SharePoint group to add/remove other members and change the settings of the same group or what?

Comment: I would like every group owner (and only the owners) see all their groups they are owner of and from there add / remove members. The current people and groups page is not suitable, because they see all the groups in the site collection.

Comment: I guess it is not possible OOTB. Need to check this.